# Delaunay triangle OpenCV

Tags: opencv, indexing, triangulation, delaunay

I was wondering if it is at all possible to retrieve the indices of neighboring vertices in a `CvSubdiv2D*` subdivision using OpenCV.

```
CvSubdiv2DPoint* pt = cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg( CvSubdiv2DEdge edge );
index= pt->id;
```

So if I have a list of coordinates, I can find out that for example point 15 from the list is connected via an edge to points 300, 210, 400 and 76 from the list.

I know getting the coordinates is no problem, but I'm not interested in that. I want to be sure I'm not wasting my time trying to retrieve indices this way and otherwise try to find an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to solve this problem was by modifying the `CvPoint2D32f` struct definition inside the `types_c.h` source file in order to store the index of a point along with its coordinates after inserting it into the subdivision.

Here is a **step-by-step** procedure of what I did:

1. Open the `types_c.h` source file (which in my case is located in `~/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h`). Add an extra field to the `CvPoint2D32f` struct that will be used to store the index of the points you insert into the subdivision. For example:

   ```
   typedef struct CvPoint2D32f
   {
       float x;
       float y;
       int index;
   }
   CvPoint2D32f;
   ```
2. Build the source file again and install it.
3. Before inserting a point into the subdivision, make sure you store the index of the point, as in the following piece of code:

   ```
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       fp = cvPoint2D32f(x[i], y[i]);
       fp.index = i;
       cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdiv, fp);
   }
   ```
4. When stepping through the edges inside your subdivision you can access the index just by referring to the index field that was previously defined. For example, in my case, I did this as follows:

   ```
       CvSubdiv2DPoint* ptSub = cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg(delaunay_edge);
       CvPoint2D32f pt32f = ptSub->pt;
       whatYouWant = pt32f.index;
   ```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the best way would be to use OpenCV 2.
They have added id to the CvSubdiv2DPoint.

```
    #define CV_SUBDIV2D_POINT_FIELDS()\
         int            flags;      \
         CvSubdiv2DEdge first;      \
        CvPoint2D32f   pt;         \
         int id;
```

and

```
typedef struct CvSubdiv2DPoint
{
     CV_SUBDIV2D_POINT_FIELDS()
}
```